# how can I implement login in Paytm mini app

Tags: angular, authentication, paytm

my requirement is to integrate login functionality for the Paytm mini-app using angular.
I unboarded the app to the Paytm mini app store.
how can I implement login functionality, I followed the doc shared by Paytm team but no luck.
This is what I tried

```
this.ua = this.getAppcontainer();
    alert(this.ua);
    if (this.ua) {
      alert("before jsbridge");
      JSBridge.call(
        "paytmFetchAuthCode",
        {
          clientId: "224ffa52ad514e979129e0619cd920cc",
        },
        function (result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
      );
    } else {
      alert("inside else condition");
    }
```

```
  getAppcontainer() {
    const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    return /AppContainer/i.test(ua);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hope This code will help you a lot, Please flow this link also :
> https://developer.paytm.com/docs/miniapps/login-flow/

```
**-----Step 1-----**
 

<script>
    function ready(callback) { 
        if (window.JSBridge) {
            callback && callback();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('JSBridgeReady', callback, false);
        }
        //console.log(callback);
    }

    ready(function () {
        JSBridge.call('paytmFetchAuthCode', {
            clientId: "merchant-****-****-****"
        }, function (result) {
            // alert(result.data.authId)
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(result))     
            var someStr = result.data.authId;   
            localStorage.removeItem("paytmFetchAuthCode");      
            //localStorage.setItem('paytmFetchAuthCode', someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, '')); 
            localStorage.setItem('paytmFetchAuthCode', someStr); 
        });
    }); </script>

**-----Step 2-----**
USE SERVER SIDE >>>>>

  

     public ActionResult Index(string authId)
            {
                /*This is a base64 encoded string of “clientId:clientSecret”*/
                var Authorizationurl = "Basic bWVyY2hhbnQtc2VsZWN0LWFzdHJvLXByb2Q6WUltT2NzTdfdfdfsdf45346aEdlTEhRNGRDRFc=";
                var client = new RestClient("https://accounts.paytm.com/oauth2/v2/token");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", Authorizationurl);
                request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=authorization_code&code="+authId+"&client_id=merchant-*****-*****-****&scope=basic", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                //var result = response.Content;
                JavaScriptSerializer RjsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var Rrespdata = RjsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(response.Content);
    
                var client1 = new RestClient("https://accounts.paytm.com/v2/user?fetch_strategy=profile_info,phone_number,email");
                client1.Timeout = -1;
                var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request1.AddHeader("verification_type", "oauth_token");
                request1.AddHeader("data", Rrespdata.access_token);
                request1.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                request1.AddHeader("Authorization", Authorizationurl);
                IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
               // var ss = response1.Content;
                JavaScriptSerializer RjsonSerializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var Rrespdata1 = RjsonSerializer1.Deserialize<UserProfile>(response1.Content);
    
                return View();
            }
    
    
            public class Rootobject
            {
                public string scope { get; set; }
                public string access_token { get; set; }
                public long expires { get; set; }
            }
    
    
            public class UserProfile
            {
                public string email { get; set; }
                public Phoneinfo phoneInfo { get; set; }
                public Profileinfo profileInfo { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class Phoneinfo
            {
                public string countryCode { get; set; }
                public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class Profileinfo
            {
                public string displayName { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: How can I use the script tag inside a component typescript file, can you please give more details to understand this @Deepak Jha

Comment: @prakash you have to use server side (Ex. c#, node) for create authId, In  angular component typescript file it's not possible.

Comment: Thank Deepak Jha for your response, I resolved this issue. I posted the aswer below for reference to other

Answer (score 0):

Use window['JSBridge'] to access JSAPI in Typescript file, like below

```
function ready(callback) { 
        if (window.JSBridge) {
            callback && callback();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('JSBridgeReady', callback, false);
        }
        //console.log(callback);
    }

    ready(function () {
        window['JSBridge'].call('paytmFetchAuthCode', {
            clientId: "merchant-****-****-****"
        }, function (result) {
            // Your logic goes here 
        });
    });
```